# How to call some mxml function from class?

Tags: actionscript-3, mxml

I have 2 files: Main.mxml with application and one MyObject.as.
I create the instance of MyObject in mxml and can call its every public function from mxml. But what if for some reason I need to call some function declared in mxml from MyObject class? How to do that? I thought that I could pass the reference to main.mxml class into this object but I couldn't figure out what exact class is it (it inherits Application, right, but what exact class is it?)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is of type Main (it takes on the name of the mxml file). You can add a static variable and getter method to it:

```
private static var _instance : Main;

public static function get instance () : Main {
    return _instance;
}
```

Then let instance refer to `this` after the application is complete:

```
private function applicationCompleteHandler():void
{
    _instance = this;
}
```

Don't forget to set `applicationComplete="applicationCompleteHandler"` in your `<mx:Application>` tag.
After that you can call `Main.instance` from anywhere in your program to access the methods and variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you are instantiating the MyObject class in your Main.mxml, you could also accomplish access to a method in Main by passing the method as a Function into the object.

Suppose you have in Main.mxml the function:

```
private function doSomething():*{
  ...
}
```

With an appropriate setter in MyObject.as:

```
private var _mainFunction:Function;

public function set mainFunction(f:Function):void
{
    _mainFunction = f;
}
```

Then you can pass the method when you instantiate the MyObject class in the mxml:

```
<*:MyObject mainFunction='doSomething'/>
```

And now you just call `_mainFunction` in the MyObject.as code whenever you need it.

Of course, Weltraumpirat's suggestion would be more efficient if you needed to access more than one method and/or variable on your Application.